# ASP.net input fields reset and Session times Azure

Tags: azure, session, session-timeout

I have a website developed in ASP.net and hosted on Azure as a web application.
The website is designed to take data from a 3rd party application, enable my users to add several fields manually and then save the data.

Here's how it works - 
1. The user pulls some data from a file. The data he pulled is saved in "Session" and a table is filled. Each field in the table has a unique ID indicating the data type and which file it was pulled from.
2. When the user clicks save, the table is first "Refilled" from the "Session" and then, because the have new fields have same ID as before, the system knows which data to fill where.

Everything works great, except for when the user takes too long to fill the data. The Session information just disappears.
From my understanding the "Session" in Azure is not very reliable and I need a different solution.
Even setting  in Web.Config didn't solve the problem.
All I want is for both the Session and the input fields to remain for at least 60 minutes.

My question is - What is the easiest quickest solution to my problem?

Options I considered - 
* Save the data in cookies instead of Session.
* Session State Provider for Azure Cache for Redis. (Does installing the package automatically solve my problem or do I need to setup a new service? Does it cost more money?)
* Auto-Refresh with a timer on the client side.

Comment: IMHO, easiest would be to pull the data at the time of submission if it is not present in the session.

Comment: You mean gather the data from the name of the fields currently on the page instead of the Session?